# How does Lombok.val actually work?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

[Lombok.val](https://projectlombok.org/features/val.html) allows you to

> use val as the type of a local variable declaration instead of
>   actually writing the type. When you do this, the type will be inferred from the initializer expression. The local variable will also be made final.

So instead of

```
final ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can write

```
val example = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

I've tried to do some research into how this actually works but there doesn't seem to be a huge amount of information. Looking at [the github page](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/val.java), I can see that `val` is an annotation type. The annotation *type* is then used, rather than an actual annotation.

I wasn't even aware you could even use annotation types in this manner but upon testing it the following code is indeed valid. However, I'm still not sure why you would ever want to use the type in this way.

```
public class Main
{
    public @interface Foo { }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {       
        Foo bar;
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

How does Lombok process these usages if they are not annotations, but annotation *types*? To my (obviously incorrect) understanding, the syntax should look more like:

```
@Val foo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(I'm aware constraints of annotations mean the above is not valid syntax)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order for Lombok to work, the source code needs to parse without errors. That's why, as you already mentioned, `@val foo = new ArrayList<String>();` wouldn't work.

Although Lombok uses annotations, and an annotation processor, the annotation processor is only used as a means to get involved by the compiler.

Lombok does not have a registered processor for `@val`. Instead, it processes all java files, visits the whole AST and replaces `val` by the type of the initialization expression of the local variables.

For the actual replacement, for Eclipse/ecj see [this class](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/eclipseAgent/lombok/eclipse/agent/PatchVal.java) and [this one](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/eclipseAgent/lombok/eclipse/agent/PatchValEclipse.java). For javac, see [this class](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleVal.java).

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: I understand lombok.val is expected in local variables - method local variables. Why would it not work at the class & instance level. I really like the idea of scala like convention through type-inference brought in by lombok for java - as in 'val' & 'var'

Comment: What this doesn’t explain (at least to me) is how `val example = new ArrayList<String>()` doesn’t fail with `error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to val` (which is what I would expect since val isn’t declared a supertype of `ArrayList`). But from what I gather it’s because at the time lombok kicks in, the AST has been parsed but no compilation has yet taken place, i.e. only syntax has been checked, not logic.